# Why in React testing library fireevent.change not working from parent component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest, react-test-renderer

The component i am testing is taking onChange function from props. This is main function that has a child component SingleText:

```
<Box className={classes.formAddress}>
      <SingleText
        type="text"
        value={disabled ? block || "-" : block || ""}
       
        placeholder="Single text"
        maxCharLength={10}
        handleChange={(event) => onChangeBlock(event.target.value)}
        required={showRequiredText}
      />
    </Box>
```

The SingleText has Mui textfield component:

```
<TextField
    type='text'
    value={value ?? ""}
    onChange={(event) => handleOnChange(name || "", event)}
    onInput={(event) => {
      handleOnInput(event);
    }}
    label={placeholder}
    data-testid = "textfield"
  />
```

When I do the following:

```
const inputNode = container.querySelectorAll("input")[1];

screen.debug(inputNode);
await act(async () => {
  userEvent.type(inputNode, "sdf");
})
```

and screen.debg(inputNode) is showing the correct input that I want to target:

```
 <input
  aria-invalid="false"
  class="MuiInputBase-input"
  classes="[object Object]"
  maxlength="10"
  type="text"
  value="789"
/>
```

but fireevent.change is not changing the input value.

I want to test when fire event is triggered, handle change function is called.